# Web part in TFS 2015 Update 3 not able to show the vNext build definition builds

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In the TFS SharePoint site, I am trying to show the Completed Builds Web Part, I can configure the Web part for all the XAML based old builds, but it does not show me the vNext build definitions in the --Any build definition-- drop down menu.

Is it that, SharePoint integration with TFS does not support vNext build, any MSDN link that says the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint integration hasn't had much love since 2010 and has not been updated to support any of the new Build and Release management features. It should be possible to build a custom web-part that uses the TFS REST-API to visualize build status.

The official answer is: The new build system is not supported in SharePoint and Report Server.

I'm not sure is there is any MSDN link that shows this, the fact that there is no mention of SharePoint in the new build system documentation on MSDN and Visualstudio.com is probably the only indication you'll find.